# wp7 dark theme, white background, keyboard causes flickering black

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I noticed strange behaviour. Set white background in my application (e.g. for Grid LayoutRoot in xaml) and then expand keyboard clicking on input/Textbox on page. After this click button in ApplicationBar which redirects to another page (do NOT close the keyboard!) and for a little moment black background is displayed on the place where was keyboard and then I am redirected.

Does anybody experienced this behaviour? Any solution?

P.S. I really want my application to be with white background for every theme - dark/light.

P.S.2 There is a workaround for appbar flickering:

[How can you prevent the ApplicationBar flickering on the WP7 white theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748552/how-can-you-prevent-the-applicationbar-flickering-on-the-wp7-white-theme)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the emulator for testing the application. Try the same in device. Still you face any issue make a feedback.

Comment: issue is on device...tested on multiple devices